# QR code scanne camera not working properly in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am working on QR code scanner project. I took two activity such as main and scan. There are one EditText view and one button in the main activity. Here If you click on button scan activity run and scan QR code. Then the result will be showed in EditText. When I click on the button, at first all works properly. But clicking further more, it will not show the result in EditText.

Here is the MainAcivity.java:

```
    package com.example.scanner_v1;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SCAN = 100;
       private EditText editText;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScanActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_SCAN);
            }
        });
     }
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,@Nullable Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(resultCode,resultCode,data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SCAN && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            String barcode = data.getStringExtra("barcode");
            editText.setText(barcode);
        }
     }
  }
```

Here is the ScanActivity.java:

```
package com.example.scanner_v1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
   private SurfaceView surfaceView;
   private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
   private CameraSource cameraSource;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    // Create BarcodeDetector and CameraSource
    barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();

    // Check for camera permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != 
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
         {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
      } else {
        startCamera();
      }
   }

   private void startCamera() {
     try {
         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             return;
        }
        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() > 0) {
                String barcodeValue = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("barcode", barcodeValue);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
             }
         }
      });
 }

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
 @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startCamera();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    barcodeDetector.release();
    cameraSource.release();
}
private void stopCamera() {
    if (cameraSource != null) {
        cameraSource.stop();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startCamera(); // Restart the camera preview when the activity resumes
}



  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      stopCamera(); // Stop the camera preview when the activity pauses
  }
}
```

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
     }

    android {
    namespace 'com.example.scanner_v1'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scanner_v1"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   

     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
  }


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //Barcode
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

}
```

Can you please suggest me a possible solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Move the initialization code out of the `startCamera()` method as you are reinitializing `cameraSource` and `barcodeDetector` again when you are clicking on `startCamera()`, objects should be initialized only once in the onCreate() method of the ScanActivity.

In your ScanActivity Override the `onBackPressed()` method and call finish() to close the activity and release the camera objects.

Here is a sample snippet from your example:

Do following in `onCreate()` funtion:

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
   private SurfaceView surfaceView;
   private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
   private CameraSource cameraSource;

@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

      surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

      barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
      cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();

      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != 
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
         {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
      } else {
         startCamera();
      }
   }
```

Update `onDestroy()` & `onBackPressed()` like this:

```
@Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      if (barcodeDetector != null) {
         barcodeDetector.release();
      }
      if (cameraSource != null) {
         cameraSource.stop();
         cameraSource.release();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
      finish();
   }
```